# content of json array - how to get all elements using js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the content of an array (unknown size) inside a json string.

The following:

```
var text = '[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "54426dbfe4b0a1df0eb4a0f6"} , "user" : "fran" , "fecha" : "18/10/2014" , "time" : "7"} , { "_id" : { "$oid" : "54426efae4b00975f860fc06"} , "user" : "elle" , "fecha" : "18/10/2014" , "time" : "9" , "w" : { "w1" : "dog, dok" , "w2" : "cat, kat", "w3" : "pork, porc"}} ]';

obj = JSON.parse(text); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
//obj[0].score;
//obj[0].user;
//obj[1].w.w1;
for (var i in obj[1].w) {
console.log(i);
}
```

How can I loop through and get all values of "w" ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much got it, all you need inside that for loop is `obj[1].w[i]` to access each value.

Keep in mind, this code is very dependent on it always being the second object in the array, you should make it more dynamic or check for errors along the way.

Comment: Thank you, I'm marking this as the correct answer, not only because it works, but because the extra tip on considering to make it more dynamic. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following

```
for (var i in obj[1].w) {
  console.log(obj[1].w[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need something `recursive`.
Here's something short that I've written, you may want to expand this:

```
function print(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'string') {
            console.log(key + ':' + obj[key]);
        } else {
            console.log(key + ' recursive');
            print(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}

var text = '[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "54426dbfe4b0a1df0eb4a0f6"} , "user" : "fran" , "fecha" : "18/10/2014" , "time" : "7"} , { "_id" : { "$oid" : "54426efae4b00975f860fc06"} , "user" : "elle" , "fecha" : "18/10/2014" , "time" : "9" , "w" : { "w1" : "dog, dok" , "w2" : "cat, kat", "w3" : "pork, porc"}} ]';

var myObj = JSON.parse(text);
print(myObj);
```

And here's your [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wjzy7e9q/).

Comment: thank you, indeed I can expand on this, however needed something "fast" and would have need to parse a little bit more using this solution. Best regards.